# Using the (!cin >> x) to detect wrong user input

Tags: c++, input, io, cin

This is what I am working with, my code is supposed to read user input which makes sure that the user enters a value of 1, 2 or 0. Any other value and it spits out an arror message which prompts the user to try again. Now it does all that but I am having an issues optimizing it:

- When I input any of the right numbers it doesn't register it the first time, I have to enter the value again in order for trhe program to work.

  ```
  int LogicCalculator::m_userChoice(int &number)
  {
  number = num;//assignment
  //output
  std::cout<<"Selection: ";
  //input
  std::cin>>number;
  //Error Checking
  while((number < 0 || number > 3) || !(cin >> number))
  {
  cin.sync(); //discard unread characters in input buffer
  cin.clear(); //clear bad input flag

  cout<<"Only 1, 2 or 0 are acceptable entries. Exception No."<<endl;
  cout<<"Press Enter to Try Again"<<endl;

  if(cin.ignore())
  {
      system("cls");//clears the screen after the user presses Enter
  }

  m_Menu();
  m_userChoice(number);
  }
  return number;
  };
  ```

If anyone knows how to solve this, I will b much obliged.

Comment: while(!(cin >> number) || number < 0 || number > 3) //read in next number before evaluating

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, unfortunately now both right and wrong entries have to be typed in twice because it does nor recognize them the first time

Comment: Just remove the line where you read in number for the first time ... std::cin>>number;

Comment: One more question though, how do I make it though it also detects if a user entered a blank answer?

Comment: Test whether the state flags indicate an error or whether a value for the datatype was read successfully.  You can access the state with cin.rdstate().

Comment: If you're expecting one of {0, 1, 2}, then the invalid range condition should be `number < 0 || number > 2`.